# Accessible error messages

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

In my application there are few field validations which fires on blur. Error message container is wrapped with a DIV which has role=alert. So when user entered an invalid input and then press tab key screen reader announce the error message to user but this cut off the reading the label and relevant information currently user is in now.

This is scenario has been identified as an accessibility issue. Any assistance to fix this issue would be very helpful.

Sample markup as follows.

```
<label class="label" for="view-184">Payment amount</label>
<input id="view-184" type="text" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Please enter a dollar value" aria-describedby="form-input-text-error-view166-required">

<div class="error" role="alert" aria-live="polite" style="">        
            <span id="form-input-text-error-view166-custom-format" class="error-custom-format" style="display: none;">Enter a valid dollar value</span>           
            <span id="form-input-text-error-view166-required" class="error-required">Dollar value is required.</span>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to meet an accessibility consultant and able get the answer. His answer was we don't need to add role="alert" for error messages which triggers on blur/change. All we have to do is when user click on submit button focus on the first field which is invalid. Also we can link field with error messages using aria-describedby tag.

Answer (score -1):

Do not use inline error messages this always create focus issues and encounter failing success criteria Level A 2.4.3 Focus Order and 1.3.2 Meaningful Sequence. Rather than using inline error message use on submit summary message providing same error message at the beginning of form. This may handy for Assistive Technologies and will solve your problem with the same code.

Comment: Error messages not creating any focus issues. role alert is the one which kills the announcement. However if i get rid of role alert then there won't be an announcement on blur.